# Apache Camel 3.7.3 and transaced() isolation

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

Let's say I have a route

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    public void configure() {
        from("file:src/data?noop=true")
                .transacted()
                .bean("accountService","credit")
                .bean("accountService","debit");
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using transacted(), I know how to choose transaction propagation policy, i.e
`REQUIRED_NEW`, `PROPAGATION_MANDATORY`, etc.

However, I've no idea on how to change transacted() isolation level, i.e how to set it
to isolation level `SERIALIZABLE`?

NOTES:

I'm using

```
JAVA 11
SpringBoot 2.4.5
Apache Camel 3.7.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to play with custom isolation levels, I think you have to create a `SpringTransactionPolicy` and provide a `TransactionTemplate` instance : see [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-spring/2.17.3/org/apache/camel/spring/spi/SpringTransactionPolicy.html#SpringTransactionPolicy(org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate))

Doing this, you will be able to [specify](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/DefaultTransactionDefinition.html#setIsolationLevel-int-) the wanted isolation level :

```
TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
transactionTemplate.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ);
transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
SpringTransactionPolicy customPolicy = new SpringTransactionPolicy(transactionTemplate);

from("...")
    .policy(customPolicy)
```

Answer (score 0):

The transacted method may refer to a specific bean holding the wished transaction policy:

```
.transacted("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED")
```

Alternatively, in case of `SpringRouteBuilder`, you can use `Policy` objects:

```
public void configure() {
        
    Policy myPolicy = bean(SpringTransactionPolicy.class, "PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW"));
    ...

    from("...")
        .policy(myPolicy)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm looking not how to set transaction propagation, but 
how to add transaction isolation, i.e DEFAULT, READ_COMMITTED, READ_UNCOMMITTED, REPEATABLE_READ, SERIALIZABLE, but all I can find is how to set propagation level, i.e  PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW